# Laravel : login from one subdomain to another subdomain : session issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I am using Sentry on laravel 4.2 in one application with muti-subdomain (every domain have different users) : i want to login from one subdomain(domain-a.maindomain.com) to another subdomain(domain-b.maindomain.com) without persisting session across subdomain.

Any one have idea how can i achieve this with laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think Since the Laravel authentication system uses cookies to manage the session, you actually need to login the user on each subdomain you're going to use. To avoid that, you can use another session driver like database. and what `@SUB-HDR` give you in his comment is a good way too do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Laravel before version 5.1 but there is part of the documentation which relates to authentication:

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security

```
$user = User::find(1);

Auth::login($user);
```

With this you may be able to authenticate a user from one of your domains to the other. You would need to pass something from the first domain to the second domain which is a unique common attribute between the two user models and then authenticate the matching user.

Answer (score 0):

in (php / mysql) we can made a row called `IslogedIn`(or something else you prefer) in All your Databases so they''ll look like :

```
     //---------------------------------------------
     //  (main database)    --> site1.com
     //   ------------------------------------------
     //  | id  | username  | password |  IslogedIn  |
     //  |-----|-----------|----------|-------------|
     //  |  1  |  jhony    |   pass   |      0      |
     //  |-----|-----------|----------|-------------|


     //---------------------------------------------
     //  (2nd database)    --> site2.com
     //   ------------------------------------------
     //  | id  | username  | password |  IslogedIn  |
     //  |-----|-----------|----------|-------------|
     //  |  1  |  jhony    |   pass   |      1      |
     //  |-----|-----------|----------|-------------|
```

here for example we see the user is logged in `2nd database` 
 
so the value will be : `IslogedIn = 1`
  
and we gonna use that in all our domains 
 and from "login.php" (in Laravel it can be somthing else) , from "login.php" we mark `IslogedIn = 1` if the user logged in by using some mysql orders .

after that we connect all databases using a scrip page and name it something like : 'checkout.php' in both domains folders and write in it :

- **1 -** for old php versions :

  ```
  $Db_Main_con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password ); 
  $Db_2nd_con  = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password , true);  
  //-------------------------------------------------------------
  $Db_Main_Select = mysql_select_db("Database_name1", $Db_Main_con);
  $Db_2nd_Select  = mysql_select_db("Database_name2", $Db_2nd_con );
  //-------------------------------------------------------------
  $Db_main = mysql_query("select * from users where id = :id", $Db_Main_Select);
  $Db_2nd  = mysql_query("select * from users where id = :id", $Db_2nd_Select);
  ```
- **2 -** for new version is Generally similar only some changes in the past code , 
   such as `mysql` to `mysqli` . read this article : [mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

> and I'm not familiar with Laravel so ofc you change the "$host_main_name" and "$username" and ( table name )..... etc to feet your script

and from every db call the row : (IslogedIn) in a `$string`.

then we go to check if the user is Logedin in all Db we have :

```
    if ( $Db_Main->IslogedIn  || $Db_2nd->IslogedIn  )
     {
      // ----->> your login code or relogin code here
      //         + sessions and cookies and reloud link and all other stuff 

     }
```

then we close the script with `$Db_Main->close(); $Db_2nd->close(); .... etc` when the checkout is end .

Comment: Interesting way of doing it :). I assume you are maintaining a legacy system? Those `mysql` statements are begging to be updated to `mysqli` lol

Comment: @Spholt , it **depend** on what php version he have , and he didnt mention that , the important thing is the way and the solution, If he able to understand the general manner , the rest easy to change like `mysql` to `mysqli` simply by reading the article i mention in my comment up below